# Logic to render a component only once

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I need help with creating a logic for my React component. If the divider line appears once on the page it should not be rendered again.

So, if I add the component to the page it styles the text underneath. But if I try to add the component again to the page, the divider line/styling should be ignored. I should only be able to add it once

This is my code:

```js
import React from 'react';
const Divider = () => (
  <>
    <hr className="divider"/>
  </>
);
```

```css
/* Seperate css file */
hr.divider {
  height: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-top: solid 1px #cdcdcd;
}

hr.divider ~ p.story-text {
  font-size: 0.90rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  line-height: 1.75rem;
  color:#707174;
  @include text-styles(.75rem, 1.75em, "Gordita");
  @include breakpoint(tablet) {
    @include text-styles(.90rem, 2em, "Gordita");
  }
}

hr.divider ~ p.story-text:last-of-type {
  border-top: solid 1px red;
}
```

Comment: Logic would go in the parent component. Problem statement needs to be refined further. I am not sure but why can’t you put divider component only once in the parent component. That should suffice

Comment: Like Ravi said, the line is not responsible for rendering itself, it's just a line. The thing that renders the line (the parent component) is responsible for controlling the number of lines rendered.

Comment: So if I add the component to the page it styles the text underneath. But if I try to add the component again to the page, the divider line/styling should be ignored. I should only be able to add it once

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the component LifeCycle tools provided by ReactJS. `ComponenDidMount()` loads the only once when the class is loaded but the `render()` function is called on each action of the user or the app. Here is a link to ReactJS docs telling how to use `ComponentDidMount()`: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to add a condition in the parent component (the one that calls Divider), but given the current snippets:

```
const Divider = () => (
  let dividers = document.getElementsByClassName('divider')
  if (dividers.length > 0) {
    return null
  } else {
    return <hr className="divider"/>
  }
);
```

This will *not* stop your component from rendering. It will *only* stop more than one `hr` from rendering.